# Creating a number gird in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a number grid in Java that would look like this:

```
789   
456    
132
```

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create grid

        int [] [] grid = new int [3][3];
                grid [0][0] = 7;
                grid [1][0] = 8;
                grid [2][0] = 9;
                grid [0][1] = 4;
                grid [1][1] = 5;
                grid [2][1] = 6;
                grid [0][2] = 1;
                grid [1][2] = 2;
                grid [2][2] = 3;

    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;


        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.println(grid[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

}

the result that I'm getting is:

```
7    
4     
1 

8     
5     
2     

9     
6     
3
```

Any suggestions on to where I am going wrong? Many thanks in advance

Comment: just change this `System.out.println(grid[i][j] + " ");` to this `System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");`

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println()` prints a newline every time. Instead use `System.out.print()` in the inner loop. Also you need to switch `i` and `j` when printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.print(grid[j][i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest to check rows and columns numeration. Since data is printed line-by-line, it's more reasonable to treat nesting arrays (`i`) as rows, and `j` would be a column index.

Answer (score 1):

use `System.out.print(grid[j][i] + " ");`  you need to swap the position of`i` and `j` because your numbers entered are in columns whereas you want them to be printed in rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {    
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
           System.out.print(grid[j][i] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
```

**output**

```
7 8 9 
4 5 6 
1 2 3
```